# How to get notify whenever a new files is added to directory in FTP server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ftp

I want to get notify whenever the new files added to a directory in FTP server. Is there any method to tell me that new files are added?

Comment: Polling. FTP doesn't have a watch feature.

Comment: can we download newly added files from particular directory in FTP?

Answer (score 0):

FTP does not support this natively. Hence you do one of the following:

1. write a short script to watch the directory  and send an email/notification (just a few lines Python)
2. use an existing module, aka pywatch
3. use an orchestration operator such as Airflow sensor, if your files are part of a larger process and you want to trigger jobs when the files arrive